# JQuery row selector is not working properly if table is updated dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table-TB1 which has 20 rows. Top 2 rows and bottom 2 rows are kind of headers in it. Now through one AJAX call I get the new table as html with the same structure. Then I remove the first 2 and last 2 rows from that html and then insert the html into my table TB1 just above the 2nd last row. Code looks like the following in my AJAX call function:

```
     var op = $(html);//html returned by AJAX call
        var tblData = op.find("#myTable > tbody");
        var $tblData = $(tblData );
        $tblData.find('tr:first').remove();//remove first 2 lines of headers from response
        $tblData.find('tr:first').remove();
        $tblData.find('tr:last').remove();//remove the last 2 headers rows
        $tblData.find('tr:last').remove();


       //add data just after the last data row
       $("#TB1 tr:nth-last-child(2)").before($tblData .html());
       $("#TB1 tr:last").remove(); //sometimes I need remove the last 1 header row on some condition
```

Now my table-TB1 has 20(old rows) + 16(new rows after removing headers) = 36 rows.
When I do a length check on rows of TB1, it gives me 36 which is correct.
But when put some selector in JQuery to read `nth-child` or `nth-last-child` then it doesn't work properly. Sometimes it doesn't return the newly added rows and return nothing. Like `nth-child(24)` will give me nothing but `nth-child(26)` will return the row at 24th number. Same goes with `nth-last-child`.
So somehow this dynamically adding and deleting the row is messing up with the selectors.
What is the way to deal with this situation?

Comment: So long as you make the `nth-child` selector call at the right time then there is no reason what you have should not work. Unfortunately you've not shown your code so no one can help you.

Comment: Have you tried running the running the initial updates in one function and then executing the `nth-last-child` after the function? It could be that the `nth-last-child` is being evaluated before the ajax call has completed (since there's nothing to indicate that it should be waiting until the ajax has finished).

Comment: I have done all these table update in AJAX done method to ensure that ajax is completed. And once the table is updated then a new method is called to fetch rows and do some calculation. I have found a weird thing that $tblData is having 3 hidden fields at the end outside tr. This is the root cause of the issue. After removing them its working fine. But what I didn't understand is that $("#TB1 tr").length doesn't count them but $("#TB1 tr:nth-child(24)") returns null if its at hidden field.

Answer (score 0):

Try to find the last row again.

```
$("#TB1").find("tr:last").remove()
```

It all depends on the state of table in which it was at the time you defined the variables.

may be you should use a function that would return the last row.

```
function getLastRowFromTable(talbe){
  return $(table).find("tr:last");
}

getLastRowFromTable('#TB1').remove();
```

This way you will alway get the current last row.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a lot of code here, which makes it hard to help you, but I can assume that your issue can easily be resolved by using the .done() function on your ajax call.

So basically something like this:

```
  $.ajax({
   //WHATEVER YOUR AJAX CALL DOES TO RETURN THE HTML.
  }).done(function(html)){
 var op = html;//html returned by AJAX call
    var tblData = op.find("#myTable > tbody");
    var $tblData = $(tblData );
    $tblData.find('tr:first').remove();//remove first 2 lines of headers from response
    $tblData.find('tr:first').remove();
    $tblData.find('tr:last').remove();//remove the last 2 headers rows
    $tblData.find('tr:last').remove();


   //add data just after the last data row
   $("#TB1 tr:nth-last-child(2)").before($tblData .html());
   $("#TB1 tr:last").remove(); //sometimes I need remove the last 1 header row on some condition
 });
```

This should ensure the javascript is only executed once you the ajax function is done returning your data (Which could be your problem, since ajax is asynchronous and therefore your browser doesn't wait for it to finish before continuing with what it's supposed to do c: